# Autocompletion of tag names when using acts_as_taggable_on gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, acts-as-taggable-on

So I'm using [this](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete) gem for autocompletion. As stated in the **Usage** section, it requires us to add a `autocomplete :classname, :method` line in the controller of the model whose attribute we're trying to autocomplete. So for instance (extracted from the docs):

**Model**

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
end

create_table :brand do |t|
  t.column :name, :string
end
```

**Controller**

```
class ProductsController < Admin::BaseController
  autocomplete :brand, :name
end
```

**Routes**

```
resources :products do
  get :autocomplete_brand_name, :on => :collection
end
```

I'm using the [acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem for my tags. Each tag has a `name` attribute, which I'm trying to autocomplete. Now, I'm not sure what class name to use in the `autocomplete :classname, :method` line in TagsController. The name of the class is ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag but I get an error when I use that:

**TagsController**

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController

  autocomplete :ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag, :name

  def index
    @tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all
  end

  def show
    @tag =  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find_by(name: params[:name])
    @posts = Post.tagged_with(@tag.name).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).order('created_at DESC')
  end

end
```

**Routes**

```
resources :tags, param: :name, only: [:index, :show] do
  get :autocomplete_ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag_name, :on => :collection
end
```

**Error after `rake routes`**

`TypeError: :ActsAsTaggableOn is not a class/module`

I tried both `tag` and `tags` as the class name. They didn't return an error, however, but they simply didn't work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the exact code of your controller? The column in `:ActsAsTaggableOn` looks strange..

Comment: @MarekTakac I updated the post with TagsController. The ProductsController is actually just an example controller extracted from the gem docs that I provided to show where the `autocomplete` line is supposed to go

Answer (score 1):

`autocomplete ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag, :name` should do the trick :). Alternatively try `autocomplete 'ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag', :name`.

The problem is that you are using symbol instead of constant - class names are constants...

Comment: Hmm using `autocomplete ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag, :name` seemed to have fixed the problem in the controller. But now it's catching a `TypeError: :autocomplete_ActsAsTaggableOn is not a class/module` error in **routes**. I've updated the post with extract from `routes.rb`

Comment: Try using string: `get 'autocomplete_acts_as_taggable_on_tag_name', :on => :collection` or `get 'autocomplete_acts_as_taggable_on::tag_name', :on => :collection`.

Comment: Neither works... The second one returns an `ArgumentError: Missing :action key on routes definition, please check your routes.` error